# Add close button div to close the boxing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djxnznen)

Preview is shown in div box. I want to add close option on right top. How could be done so that when user click on it box should be disabled.

**Code Snippet**

```css
.duyurular {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: #212121;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
.duyurular > i {
    background-color: #27ae60;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0 16px 0 -16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 42px;
}
.otomesaj {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Exo 2",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px auto 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 680px;
}
.otomesaj ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.duyurus {
    color: #212121;
    display: none;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="duyurular" original-title="">
<i class="fa fa-bullhorn" original-title=""></i>
<div class="otomesaj" original-title="">
 <ul>
         <li class="duyurus" style="display: list-item;">Temamız yapım aşamasındadır sürekli yenilenmekte ve geliştirilmektedir.</li>
  <li class="duyurus" style="display: none;">denem amaçlı yazılmıştır gerekli değişiklikleri header kısmından yapabilirsiniz...</li>
        <li class="duyurus" style="display: none;">deneme için yazıldı temamız özel yapım bir temadır kesinlikle emek temasıdır saygı duyalım.</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,this may help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.right').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().hide('slow');
   })
})
```

```css
.duyurular {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: #212121;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
.duyurular > i {
    background-color: #27ae60;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0 16px 0 -16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 42px;
}
.otomesaj {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Exo 2",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px auto 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 680px;
}
.otomesaj ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.duyurus {
    color: #212121;
    display: none;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-align: left;
}
.right{
  position:relative;
  text-align:right;
left:350px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="duyurular" original-title="">
<i class="fa fa-bullhorn" original-title="">s</i>
<div class="otomesaj" original-title="">
 <ul>
        <li class="duyurus" style="display: list-item;">Temamız yapım aşamasındadır sürekli yenilenmekte ve geliştirilmektedir.</li>
  <li class="duyurus" style="display: none;">denem amaçlı yazılmıştır gerekli değişiklikleri header kısmından yapabilirsiniz...</li>
        <li class="duyurus" style="display: none;">deneme için yazıldı temamız özel yapım bir temadır kesinlikle emek temasıdır saygı duyalım.</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
   <button class="right">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your Fiddle :)

http://jsfiddle.net/djxnznen/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/djxnznen/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.right').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().hide('slow');
   })
})
```

```css
.duyurular {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: #212121;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
.duyurular > i {
    background-color: #27ae60;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0 16px 0 -16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 42px;
}
.otomesaj {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Exo 2",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px auto 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 680px;
}
.otomesaj ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.duyurus {
    color: #212121;
    display: none;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-align: left;
}
.right{
  position:relative;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="duyurular" original-title="">
<i class="fa fa-bullhorn" original-title="">s</i>
<div class="otomesaj" original-title="">
 <ul>
        <li class="duyurus" style="display: list-item;">Temamız yapım aşamasındadır sürekli yenilenmekte ve geliştirilmektedir.</li>
  <li class="duyurus" style="display: none;">denem amaçlı yazılmıştır gerekli değişiklikleri header kısmından yapabilirsiniz...</li>
        <li class="duyurus" style="display: none;">deneme için yazıldı temamız özel yapım bir temadır kesinlikle emek temasıdır saygı duyalım.</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="right">x</div>
</div>
```

They are all the same, but my mouse hates me(I click 1 time and he perform a click storm...).

Answer (score 1):

Add it this way.

```
 <style>
 #preview {
height: 70%;
width: 70%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top:30;
left: 20;
background-color: #ff00ff;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
}
  .closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 25px;
font-size: 36px !important;
margin-left: 50px;
}

 </style>
 <body>
 <div id="preview">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn"
  onclick="closePreview()">x</a>
  <p style="text-align:center" >Your Content</p>
  </div>
 <script>
function closePreview(){
var btn = document. getElementById("preview");
btn.style.display="none"
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give an id to your div and add an onlcick event on it here i gave the id myDiv

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.onclick = function() { myDiv.style.display = 'none'; };
```

here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djxnznen/2/)